# Where is the May 31, 2023 update to the Code of Conduct?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

The Stack Overflow website is full of notices about a May 31, 2023 update to the Code of Conduct.  However, it does not seem to have a link to this document.

The notice in the header: links a blogpost, not a document.

The link in the sidebar: links to a blogpost, not a document.

The giant orange "Code of Conduct" button in the blogpost, with a labelled titled "Code of Conduct", in a rectangular frame that implies it links to a document: links back to the same blogpost, not a document.

The footer:  The Code of Conduct does not appear to be anywhere in these links.

Where is the Code of Conduct?  How much does it cost to access it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: That link you state *isn't* the code of conduct, in fact *is* the CoC...

Comment: The link in the sidebar goes to a blogpost, and that blogpost says `On May 31st, we rolled out an updated Code of Conduct to help reflect our commitment to the safety of everyone who visits our sites.`. That `Code of Conduct` is a link to the actual CoC

Comment: `/conduct` is the universal URL to reach the official CoC on any site, including MSO

Comment: I have to admit, it's not easy to find back once one has dismissed the Banner... It's not in the Footer next to `Legal` + `Terms of Services` where I would have expected a direct link..., nor linked from that `ToS` page, (`Legal` has no use btw as it links/redirects to the same `ToS` page), I finally find it under the `Help` link (in the Footer), in the `Our model` section + also linked to from the `Expected Behavior` link/page (with a different URL strangely...). // => `Footer` => `Help` => `Code of Conduct`.

Comment: You know there are concerns about how the site's being monetized when someone asks what it costs to read the code of conduct.

Comment: Okay, so if that's the URL, where in that URL is the link to the Code of Conduct?  Where can I actually read the document?

Comment: What exactly are you seeing at https://stackoverflow.com/conduct?  If you aren't seeing the code of conduct there, could you post a screenshot of what you *are* seeing?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The messages in the header and sidebar have been removed, so it seems there was no Code of Conduct update to worry about.  False alarm.

Comment: This is untrue. There was indeed an update to the Code of Conduct. As was **repeatedly** explained to you in the comments above, the new Code of Conduct can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/conduct , which **is** where the header banner linked you to and **is not** a blogpost but in fact the actual Code of Conduct. That is different from the sidebar link (which is indeed to the blog post). The blog post also includes a link to the new Code of Conduct in the first paragraph. The header banner was not "removed" per se; rather, it disappears *for you* after you acknowledge it.

Answer (score 1):

> The notice in the header: links a blogpost, not a document.

Untrue; it links to [the actual Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). It has not to my knowledge been "removed"; it can be *dismissed* on a per-user basis.

> The link in the sidebar: links to a blogpost, not a document.

True.

> The giant orange "Code of Conduct" button in the blogpost, with a labelled titled "Code of Conduct", in a rectangular frame that implies it links to a document: links back to the same blogpost, not a document.

That isn't a button and AFAIK isn't intended to be interpreted as one. It's just a decorative image. I have no idea why they thought it would be a good idea to self-link it.

That said: the first paragraph of the blog post is as follows:

> Throughout Stack Overflow’s 15-year journey, we have always prioritized the well-being and safety of the community. This is actually one of the things that most attracted me to this community: for years when I worked in other places, I watched to see how Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange worked to protect users. I’ve learned that as culture shifts and new threat types emerge, our guidelines must mature and flex to meet new challenges. On May 31st, we rolled out an updated [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) to help reflect our commitment to the safety of everyone who visits our sites.

As I have reproduced here, the text "Code of Conduct" links to the actual code of conduct, which once again for reference is at https://stackoverflow.com/conduct.

> The footer: The Code of Conduct does not appear to be anywhere in these links.

True, but there wasn't a link there for the *old* Code of Conduct, either.

> Where is the Code of Conduct? How much does it cost to access it?

It is free to access. Aside from the aforementioned, it is also linked from the [main help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), directly underneath the header "Our model".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me where I can find a link to the Code of Conduct?